Why does docker compose watch command not do hot reload?
App.py
import time

import redis
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
cache = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379)

def get_hit_count():
    retries = 5
    while True:
        try:
            return cache.incr('hits')
        except redis.exceptions.ConnectionError as exc:
            if retries == 0:
                raise exc
            retries -= 1
            time.sleep(0.5)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    count = get_hit_count()
    return 'Hello World from Dock! I have been seen {} times.\n'.format(count)

compose.yaml
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: .
          target: /code
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

requirements.txt
flask
redis

Dockerfile
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.10-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run", "--debug"]

I am using m1 Mac and Docker desktop.
I was expectin when i use docker compose watch and run this script when i make a change ın the app.py it should also do the change when i reaload the browser but it does not.I checked a bit but could not find the reason is there anything you can help?

Compose sees a file change; how should it know what to do with that file, or if the target language even supports hot reloading?  watch: will rebuild the image and restart the container, saving you doing those steps by hand, but it will lose any state that happened to be in-memory.

As i know python should support that this is from the documents of docker.I am not sure what to do honestly i am a beginner in docker right now

I did not think Python natively supported any sort of dynamic reloading functionality.  If this is for a development environment, there's no particular reason to hide your tools inside a container, particularly since your host system likely already has Python available.  I'd use a plain virtual environment without Docker, or a higher-level Python-native tool like Pipenv or Poetry.

Hello David first of all thanks for giving me your valuable time. This is the documentation i am following https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/
I am learning new so the reason i use docker is to learn because i will use it in my future projects.

Add sync+restart
develop:
  watch:
    - action: sync+restart
      path: .
      target: /code

